# How can I exclude collections in a render layer?

Tags: python

good day. I have a group hierarchy which should be counted by scenes separately. for this, my code creates scenes, and then I manually turn off what I don’t need in a particular scene. I also have code that can exclude 1 group, but I could not adapt it to exclude everything that I do not need. Help complete[image]

```
        def include_only_one_collection(view_layer: bpy.types.ViewLayer, collection_include: bpy.types.Collection):
        for layer_collection in view_layer.layer_collection.children:
            if layer_collection.collection != collection_include:
                layer_collection.exclude = False
            else:
                layer_collection.exclude = True


    view_layer = bpy.data.scenes["1_env"].view_layers["View Layer"]
    collection_include = bpy.data.collections["space"]
    include_only_one_collection(view_layer, collection_include)

    def include_only_one_collection(view_layer: bpy.types.ViewLayer, collection_include: bpy.types.Collection):
        for layer_collection in view_layer.layer_collection.children:
            
            if layer_collection.collection != collection_include:
            
                layer_collection.exclude = False

            else:
                layer_collection.exclude = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of collection names you do want to include in the view layer.

There are a few solutions that use recursion to traverse the view layer's layer collection tree but it has some shortcomings, like you can attain the python stack recursion limit if you have a big tree. This solution uses a `while` loop instead.

```
import bpy

included_collection_list_names = ["Collection 1", "Collection 2"]
layer_collections = list(bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children)

while layer_collections:
    layer_collection = layer_collections.pop(0)
    layer_collections.extend(layer_collection.children)
    layer_collection.exclude = layer_collection.name not in included_collection_list_names
```

Here's a more in depth explanation :

```
# Replace your actual collection names here :
included_collection_list_names = ["Collection 1", "Collection 2", "Collection 3"]
for layer_collection in bpy.data.scenes["1_env"].view_layers["View Layer"].layer_collection.children:
    layer_collection.exclude = layer_collection.name not in included_collection_list_names
```

Conversely if you have a list of collection names you want to exclude :

```
excluded_collection_list_names = ["Collection 1", "Collection 2", "Collection 3"]
for layer_collection in bpy.data.scenes["1_env"].view_layers["View Layer"].layer_collection.children:
    layer_collection.exclude = layer_collection.name in excluded_collection_list_names
```

Also, instead of

```
for layer_collection in bpy.data.scenes["1_env"].view_layers["View Layer"].layer_collection.children:
```

You can use

```
for layer_collection in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children:
```

if the view layer you're trying to modify is the one currently open in the interface.

Comment: figured it out. What if I need to turn off a collection that is in a collection? This only works in main collections((

Comment: @Welet you're right ! I added an extension for this case at the top of the answer. Cheers

Comment: It won't work if you want to exclude more deeply nested collections though, as "view_layer.layer_collection.children" doesn't return all children recursively.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek Well no it doesn't, but the children are recursively added to the base list on each iteration of the while loop on line 8. Then their children are added to the list when their turn comes, and so on... Add `print([l.name for l in layer_collections])` after the `while` line to see what the loop actually does.